# mysql sum on JOINED table with different group condition

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have a query as the following

```
SELECT 
sum(price), 
count(id), 
sum case(when spec='bath' then price else 0 END) as bath_money    
FROM 
table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fkt1
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.id = table3.fkt2    
WHERE 1    
group by sale;
```

Now my problem is that table 3 has 2 rows for each row in Table 2. Table 2 is the one I actually use to add up sales and to sum price but since I need to left join for Table 3 everything is added twice. 
Would there be a way of adding up prices of table 2 ignoring all double lines generated by joining Table 3? Otherwise I'd just write another query, but I'd like to know whether I can do a sum ignoring a specific join??

Comment: Is there a way of identifying one of the 2 rows from table3 & eliminating that in the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work :

```
SELECT 
sum(price), 
count(id), 
sum(case when spec='bath' then price else 0 END) as bath_money    
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fkt1
LEFT JOIN (select * from table3 GROUP BY fkt2) table3a ON table2.id = table3a.fkt2    
group by sale;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
SELECT 
sum(t1.price), 
count(t1.id), 
sum (case when t2.spec='bath' then t2.price else 0 END) as bath_money

FROM 
table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.fkt1
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.fkt2

group by t1.sale
```

Comment: Aside from fixing the query & removing some ambiguities - how does this resolve the issue of there being two entries in table3 for each selected row in table2 - hence sum of prices is doubled.

Comment: thanks Rahul, it is pretty much the same thing doesn't solve much.

Comment: @markoc., can you post some sample data of 3 tables which will clear the confusion.